# cannot import name 'DatabaseHandler' from partially initialized module 'db_conn' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to make a database connection with db_conn and when I try to import db_conn happened this Error message, I uninstall and install again the db_conn package but didn't solve my problem.

Error Message:
from db_conn import engine, metadata_obj Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\arnaureynals\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15316\3053301630.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1> from db_conn import engine, metadata_obj File "C:\Users\arnaureynals\Anaconda3\envs\bpa\lib\site-packages\db_conn_init_.py", line 1, in  from db_conn import DatabaseHandler

ImportError: cannot import name 'DatabaseHandler' from partially initialized module 'db_conn' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\arnaureynals\Anaconda3\envs\bpa\lib\site-packages\db_conn_init_.py)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: from db_conn import engine, metadata_obj
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\arnaureynals\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_15316\3053301630.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    from db_conn import engine, metadata_obj

  File "C:\Users\arnaureynals\Anaconda3\envs\bpa\lib\site-packages\db_conn\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from db_conn import DatabaseHandler
ImportError: cannot import name 'DatabaseHandler' from partially initialized module 'db_conn' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\arnaureynals\Anaconda3\envs\bpa\lib\site-packages\db_conn\__init__.py)

Comment: Hey, not as comment. Edit your question instead.